# How to remove duplicate @JsonProperty in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a very simple JSON class with Jackson:

```java
public class Hoge {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public final int cid;

    public Hoge(@JsonProperty("id") aid){
        cid = aid;
    }
}
```

I noticed that I have to put @JsonProperty("id") in two places to convert mutually JSON string <-> JSON object, 
The first place is the field declaration and the second one is the argument of the constructor.

When I removed the first @JsonProperty, the JSON key becomes "cid", not "id". But I want the key name being "id".

When I removed the second one, I have the exception:

> No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class Series]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

I want to keep the name of field (The "cid" in the code) and the JSON key (The "id" in the code) are different.

When I removed the constructor, I have a compile error because the id have to be "final" to keep it immutable.

Does anyone knows how to remove the duplicate @JsonProperty in the example?

Comment: if you want to map the name (cid in the code, id in json), you need both annotations. Do you really need the constructor to have the parameter? If not, just remove it.

Comment: When I removed the constructor, I have a compile error because the id is "final"...

Comment: Then remove the final modifier. Or do you need it?
And what's the problem with having the annotation twice?

Comment: I want to keep the final. I just want to keep the code as clean as possible.

Comment: Why do you think `final` keeps your code cleaner?

Comment: No, I mean I want to remove duplicate annotation to keep the code clean.

Comment: And why do you need `final` then?

Comment: Besides, I keep the final to keep the field immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wants to keep the `final` modifier in the field and remove the `@JsonProperty` annotation from the constructor, you could annotate the constructor with `@JsonCreator` and rename the parameter from `aid` to `id`, as shown below:

```java
@Data
public class Hoge {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public final int cid;

    @JsonCreator
    public Hoge(int id){
        this.cid = id;
    }
}
```

Then use one of the following approaches:

### `ParanamerModule`

Register the [`ParanamerModule`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-paranamer/2.9.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/paranamer/ParanamerModule.html) in your `ObjectMappper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParanamerModule());
```

You'll need the following dependency on the classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-paranamer</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/paranamer) for details.

### `ParameterNamesModule`

Register the [`ParameterNamesModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/parameter-names/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/paramnames/ParameterNamesModule.html) module and ensure the code is compiled using the `-parameters` option:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));
```

The following dependency is required:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names) for details.